# Hide nav on scroll down and show on scroll up only when in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I trying to hide my nav on scroll down and show on scroll up only when in mobile mode. I have a example that i found from another website that uses a script that does the same only i'm not really good in unraveling and adjusting it to my situation. You see it working when the browser size is small.

[--> Example website](http://warp25.net)

I have a navigation that has two versions: one inline when in large screen size and position is absolute and the second in mobile screen size with a hamburger icon the open the menu items under each other.

[--> Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/q2dxojss/9/)

```
<header>
<nav>
    <div class="mobile-nav">
        <div class="nav-toggle"><i class="nav-icon"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="left-nav">   
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Pixelation</a></li>    
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-nav">  
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Part of the script of example website

```
   hideShowMobileNav = function(setOldScroll) {
    if (stateMap.scrollTop != stateMap.oldScrollTop && stateMap.scrollTop > 100) {
        if (stateMap.scrollTop > stateMap.oldScrollTop) {
            jqueryMap.$nav.addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            jqueryMap.$nav.removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }
    if (setOldScroll) {
        stateMap.oldScrollTop = stateMap.scrollTop;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use device detection

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

or `width()` function

or some sort of css media query

Comment: thanks but i knew that my question is more how can i make it work with the existing script or a new script. I can read and understand javascript when its there, but not that good in writing it from scratch.